# How may I output values to precision sufficient to reveal this arithmetic discrepancy between Debug and Release?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, floating-point

In my program this fragment:

```
trace.Log(
 String.Format("a= {0:F10} b= {1:F10} a<b= {2}",
  b.GetPixel(447, 517).GetBrightness(), (100F / 255F), 
  b.GetPixel(447, 517).GetBrightness() < (100F / 255F))
);
```

outputs this in Debug mode:

```
a= 0.3921569000 b= 0.3921569000 a<b= False
```

but this different result in Release mode:

```
a= 0.3921569000 b= 0.3921569000 a<b= True
```

Before I seek a way to get consistent arithmetic between the two modes, what code can I use to display the hidden precision in the varaible(s) that presumably contains the variation causing this discrepancy? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [standard numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) for exactly what you're looking for: `"r"` (for "round-trip"). It gives you a string with enough digits to guarantee that, when you parse it again, will exactly reproduce the same bits you started with.

So instead of `{0:F10}`, use `{0:r}` and you'll get all the precision available.

Comment: Just the ticket! Many thanks Joe. "R" does indeed reveal precision in the positions of the "000" of F10 above. Can you explain to me why F10 gave an apparently false result?

Comment: Assuming you're working with `double`, there are between 15 and 16 digits of precision actually available. With `f10`, you're specifically telling it to show you ten decimal places. For a number between 0.1 and 0.9, that translates to only showing 10 digits of precision.

Comment: Joe, that example uses float not double. And the false result I was asking about is F10's 0.3921569000, compared to R's 0.392156869. I say false because F10 is sufficient for all the digits shows by R, but F10's output is rouded to two digits fewer.